# How to get Moving Average and Stochastic data from what user attached in mq4?

Tags: moving-average, stochastic

How can I get data with mq4 Script from the following Graph ?
[Moving Average and Stochastic in Metatrader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V6hf.jpg)

As you can see I have attached 2 functions : Moving Average and Stochastic.

I started to write a script. But I have no ideea how can I get data from the functions attached to the script so that I can start processing

Is there a handle somewhere that returns an array? Global arrays ?

Comment: So does anybody know something ?